# Maven to SBT converter

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, maven-plugin

I went though the https://github.com/shivawu/sbt-maven-plugin read me file. But it is not clear to me. I was expecting a tutorial how to use it, to convert a maven project into sbt project.

Any help is appreciated please.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think the plugin docs it is pretty clear, but you *do* need to know SBT to use it (just like with any other build tool) and you cannot really expect a plugin writer to write that kind of documentation.

There is good docs though, checkout http://www.scala-sbt.org and in addition to that there is a Manning MEAP called 'SBT in Action' that is coming along very nicely: http://www.manning.com/suereth2/